# Inner join alias's causing issues

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

I have 4 tables.

```
create table LOCATION(
loccode Number(2) NOT NULL,
locname Varchar2 (30),
state Varchar2 (10),
population Number(7),
travelcode Number(1),
CONSTRAINT PK_LOCATION PRIMARY KEY (loccode)
);

create table DEPOT(
depid Number(4) NOT NULL,
audit_year Number(4),
address Varchar2 (30),
mgrname Varchar2 (30),
capacity Number(7),
capacity_used Number(7),
mgrgender Varchar2(10),
loccode Number(2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_DEPOT PRIMARY KEY (depid),
CONSTRAINT FK_LOCATION FOREIGN KEY (loccode) REFERENCES LOCATION

create table MANUFACTURER(
manid Number (2) NOT NULL,
manname Varchar2(30),
loccode Number(2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_MANUFACTURER PRIMARY KEY (manid),
CONSTRAINT FK_LOC FOREIGN KEY (loccode) REFERENCES LOCATION
);
create table STOCKITEM(
stkid Number(2) NOT NULL,
stkname Varchar2(30),
sellingprice Number(6,2),
purchaseprice Number(6,2),
depid Number(4) NOT NULL,
manid Number(2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_STOCKITEM PRIMARY KEY (stkid),
CONSTRAINT FK_DEP FOREIGN KEY (depid) REFERENCES DEPOT,
CONSTRAINT FK_MANUFACTURER FOREIGN KEY (manid) REFERENCES MANUFACTURER 
);
```

I am trying to generate a query that lets me see the stock id, stock name, manufacturer location and department location.

This requires 4 inner join clauses.

1 to link stockitem to depot, one to link stockitem to manufacturer, and two unique ones linking location to both depot and manufacturer.

Im using this at the moment;

```
select  
    stockitem.stkid as "STOCK ID",
    stockitem.stkname as "STOCK NAME", 
    manloc.locname as "MANUFACTURER LOCATION", 
    deploc.locname as "DEPOT LOCATION"  
from stockitem
inner join depot on stockitem.depid = depot.depid
inner join manufacturer on stockitem.manid = manufacturer.manid
inner join location  on location.locid = deploc.locid as deploc
inner join location  on location.locid = manloc.locid as manloc
order by stockitem.stkid asc;
```

however it is spitting back that the string is not properly terminated. Am I missing something here?

If I put the alias's before the 'on' (the deploc and manloc), then I get an error saying that its missing an expected operator...i.e....'on'.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: on location.locid = deploc.locid as deploc? . as is not required here.

Comment: Stop changing the code in your question but learn some SQL aliases syntax instead. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location table alias's should be after the table name and there should be no **`AS`** when aliasing tables (that's an Oracle quirk):

```
select  
stockitem.stkid as "STOCK ID",
stockitem.stkname as "STOCK NAME", 
manloc.locname as "MANUFACTURER LOCATION", 
deploc.locname as "DEPOT LOCATION"  
from stockitem
inner join depot on stockitem.depid = depot.depid 
inner join manufacturer on stockitem.manid = manufacturer.manid 
inner join location deploc on depot.loccode = deploc.loccode 
inner join location manloc on manufacturer.loccode = manloc.loccode 
order by stockitem.stkid asc;
```

You don't actually need the `AS` when aliasing columns but it makes it read easier.

Note the correct column reference in the location inner joins

Comment: `inner join location as deploc on location.locid = deploc.locid
                    *
Error at line 9:
ORA-00905: missing keyword`

Im starting to think this SQL server is a bit broken...

Comment: @user3475423 Actually, are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: my apologies, it is Oracle.

Comment: I think i see the problem, what are you joining onto the location table with?

Comment: the location tables primary key is locid.
The two tables neighboring it, have locid as foreign keys (depot and manufacturer).

I need to get a depot location, and a manufacturer location, hence the need to use aliased inner joins to prevent one from overwriting the other from location.

Comment: I changed my sql above to something more like what i would expect.  You need to relate the tables to each on the join so the depot table "loccode" matches the location table loccode etc...I think, maybe worth creating a sqlfiddle

Comment: With your latest eddit I am getting an error saying that 'from' is not where its expecting it..

`stockitem.stkid as 'STOCK ID',
                   *
Error at line 2:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: I got it using the following from n34_panda, however I removed the 'as' in the alias's for the unique inner joins on location table, and voilla!

    `inner join depot on stockitem.depid = depot.depid
    inner join manufacturer on stockitem.manid = manufacturer.manid
    inner join location  deploc on depot.loccode = deploc.loccode
    inner join location  manloc on manufacturer.loccode = manloc.loccode 
    order by stockitem.stkid asc;`

I had to use double quotes in my column alias's also. Cant show here cause of character restriction >.<

Thanks a lot for the help guys :)

Comment: I am used to SQLServer but I thought Oracle supported that (never mind).  Note the change away from locid to loccode as well.  Glad it's sorted, I updated my answer with the small amendments so you can mark it as solved

Comment: Oh....I was using locid....yeah that would have been a problem also.
The ERD I have uses locid, but the description uses loccode. Confusing.

If you could change the single quotes on the column alias's to double quotes, ittl be exactly what I got that works.

Thanks again.